# Which method reference could simplify this lambda (Foo foo) -> foo.getName()?

Tags: java, lambda

I was asked how to simplify this lambda

```
(Foo foo) -> foo.getName()
```

Any better way to write it ?

Comment: `foo -> foo.getName()`

Comment: Are both answers correct ?

Comment: @Are could you share the complete statement with what the stream is, to verify once.

Comment: `foo -> foo.getName()` may or may not be correct.  I think it depends on whether the compiler can figure out from context whether `foo` has class `Foo`.  If you were to use this in a stream's `map` method, the type of the lambda has to be `Function<? super T, ? extends R>`, and the previous code in the stream often dictates what `T` is.  So in a case like that, the compiler would be able to figure it out.  But I think you can construct cases where `(Foo foo)->foo.getName()` is legal but it's not legal to leave the `Foo` off.  The rules surrounding this are quite complicated.

Comment: On the other hand, `Foo::getName` might also be incorrect--see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @ajb agreed and that's why I thought the question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Well marking the question Unclear unless next edit. Since even the selected answer doubts the implementation without prior detailed info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo::getName`.

Assuming `getName` is an instance method with an empty parameter list in its signature, then the effect is to create an anonymous method with *one* parameter of class `Foo`, that uses that parameter as the "target reference" of the instance method call, i.e. the object to which the method call applies.  That is, it creates a method

```
return-type anonymousMethod(Foo arg) {
    return arg.getName();
}
```

which is exactly what `(Foo foo) -> foo.getName();` does.

On the other hand, this method reference:

```
abc::getName()
```

creates an anonymous method with *no* parameters, that returns `abc.getName()`, where `abc` is defined outside the lambda.

**EDIT:** I've just realized that this answer isn't entirely correct; there's a case where `(Foo foo) -> foo.getName()` *cannot* be simplified to `Foo::getName`.  This happens when `Foo` declares two methods that look like this:

```
public String getName() { ... }
public static String getName(Foo foo) { ... }
```

Now `Foo::getName` is ambiguous (and thus illegal), while `(Foo foo) -> foo.getName()` is not.